# reflection java ? extends

Tags: java, generics

Is there any difference between :

`Class<?>` and `Class<? extends Object>`  ?

Thanks

Comment: dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016017/unbounded-wildcards-in-java

Comment: and note that the answers there are more intricate (and correct) than the ones given here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is effectively the same

Answer (score 3):

Nope. They are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

The same, 'cos **every class extends Object**.

It's analogous to saying

```
class MyClass
```

and

```
class MyClass extends Object
```

are the same thing.