# What are the 'good' reasons to use <?> in Java Generics?

Tags: java, generics, idioms

Now and then in my code I find that I can solve a problem by either using a naked generic class or one with wildcards.

I have a design where a class like this:

```
Class World<T, C> { .... }
```

definitely in general is making my code cleaner than it would have been without generics.

Yet, sometimes I use

```
World theWorld;
```

or sometimes I end up with

```
World<?, ?> theWorld;
```

I do this because it seems to be what it takes to make the compiler accept it and my 
attempts to avoid them lead me to more casting or inheriting complexity.

It looks ugly and smelly to me and yet I cannot justify the added complexity it looks like I need to introduce to avoid it.

What are some cases (if any) that you believe using a naked or wildcarded generic is acceptable idiomatic Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you *could* use generics but don't *need* it in that specific situation. `<?>` tells the compiler roughly: "I know about generics, but I don't need the type now".

Maybe the type is needed in other situation. E.g. if you have a `Set` that just stores anything, like a cache, and you just don't care for the type of the elements at all. At other times you do, when you process specific elements.

It smells if you use too loosely bound type parameters (like `<?>` which is quite loose) but try to determine the type afterwards, e.g. with `instanceof` or some custom type discriminator. Then something was designed poorly.

Answer (score 4):

There is a good example (use case) of using `<?>` in the [Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) section of the Generics tutorial.

A sort summary: if you want to write a `printCollection` method which accepts all kinds of `Collection` you could use `Collection<?>` as a parameter type. You cannot use `Collection<Object>` as the parameter type for this purpose because it is not a supertype of all kinds of collections.

Using `Collection<?>` instead of "pure" `Collection` in this case is safer because you cannot add items to `Collection<?>` (except for null) in the `printCollection` method.

Comment: Ok I think that makes sense... Except I don't follow "You cannot use Collection<Object> as the parameter type for this purpose because it is not a supertype of all kinds of collections." I thought it would be... I would have thought that the reason you cannot do that is that a Collection<Object> is specifically not the same as a Collection<Foo>. Whereas, a Collection<? extends Object> would be logical but that is equivalent to Collection<?>. Can you confirm?

Comment: Collection<?> and Collection<? extends Object> are almost the same. See this answer for the minor differences: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2016382/122442

Answer (score 1):

The Wildcard also proves as very useful, when you want to store multiple objects, that are a subclass of another class.

For example:

```
Collection<? extends Shape> myShapes
```

This Collection now could keep all the objects, that are a subclass of Shape.
So you are type-safe when adding any object that is a subclass of Shape. For Example:

```
myShapes.add(new Rectangle())
myShapes.add(new Triangle())
```

Comment: Interesting! I had tried "Collection<T extends Shape> a;" and found that this was invalid. So use the "?" instead!

Comment: T works only if the class you implemented it in is in itself generic, meaning that the T will be known to the VM as soon as an object of that class has been instanciated.