# List<?> vs List<? extends Object>

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between <?> and <? extends Object> in Java Generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055389/whats-the-difference-between-and-extends-object-in-java-generics)

I found that `List<?>`and `List<? extends Object>` act in the same way. As for me, there are no difference between them. If I am not right, can you explain me the difference?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestClass {

static void func1(List<?> o, Object s) {
    o.add(null); // only null
    o.add(s); // wrong
    o.get(0);  // OK
}

static void func2(List<? extends Object> o, Object s) {
    o.add(null); // only null
    o.add(s); // wrong
    o.get(0); // OK
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    func1(new ArrayList<String>(), new Integer(1));
    func2(new ArrayList<String>(), new Integer(1));

    List<? extends Object> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
    List<?> list2 = new ArrayList<Object>();

    List<? extends Object> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<?> list4 = new ArrayList<String>();
}
}
```

Comment: There is no difference whatsoever. `extends Object` is redundant and assumed otherwise, just like writing `class F extends Object`.

Comment: I would bet they are equivalent, since all classes in Java implicitly extend `Object`.

Comment: No difference at all, it is the consequence of language design/grammar.

Comment: I don't know the Object is a class not a type.

Comment: You might also look up PECS principle (Producer Extends Consumer Super)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016017/unbounded-wildcards-in-java

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you'll be surprised ... see my answer

Answer (score 13):

It is complicated...

For any type variable `T`, the spec says http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4

> Every type variable ... has a bound. If no bound is declared for a type variable, Object is assumed.

One would think that it's true for wildcard too, and `?` should just be a shorthand for `? extends Object`.

Yet searching through the spec, there is no evidence at all that a wildcard must have an upper bound (or lower bound). The "unbounded" `?` is treated consistently distinctly from bounded wildcards.

We could deduce from subtyping rules, that `List<?>` and `List<? extends Object>` are subtypes of each other, i.e., they are *basically* the same type. (The deduction depends on the fact that `E` in `interface List<E>` has an implicit upper bound `Object`; but the rules do not require bounds on wildcards)

Nevertheless the spec treats the two differently. For example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7 `List<?>` is a reifiable type, but `List<? extends Object>` is not, which means

```
    // ok
    List<?>[] xx = {};
    // fail
    List<? extends Object>[] yy = {};

    // ok
    boolean b1 = (y instanceof List<?>);
    // fail
    boolean b2 = (y instanceof List<? extends Object>);
```

I don't understand why though. It seems perfectly fine to say a wildcard must have an upper bound and a lower bound, default to `Object` and `null type`.

Comment: But, there is this `Given a generic type declaration G<T extends B>, G<?> is roughly analogous to Some X <: B. G<X>.` under 4.5.1.

Comment: @iccthedral - applied to the `List` case, `List<?> is roughly analogous to List<X> for some X<:Object`

Comment: Well, yes. That's my point. `X <: B` should (?) be an inclusive subtype relation, however I cannot find the reference for this. It just follows since `T extends C` is inclusive as well.

Comment: Okay, I've found it. 
Maybe I wasn't clear in my previous comment; my interpretation is that there exists `X` such that `X <: Object` where `<:` is an inclusive subtype relation (And http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10 tells it is). And of course `X = Object`. Correct me if I'm wrong. However, I still see your point in code you provided, could be that it breaks the type-system somehow. I'm not sure how and why yet.

Comment: @iccthedral of course `List<?> is not List<X> where X=Object`. But whenever an object of type `List<?>` is used, we know it is a `List<X>` for some definite yet unknown `X<:Object`. That is wildcard capture. We can reason with `List<X>`, e.g. `get()` return type is `X`, which is a subtype of `Object`, so `get()` can be assigned to `Object`; `add()` argument type is X, for any `A a`, we cannot do `add(a)`, since we don't known if `A<:X`. (unless A is the null type, so `add(null)` is fine)

Comment: +1 Nice JLS detective work :)

Comment: If I caught anyone writing code that depends on the difference between `List<?>` and `List<? extends Object>`, that person would be in trouble.

Comment: [JLS8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1) - The wildcard ? extends Object is equivalent to the unbounded wildcard ?.

Comment: javac8 - allows `List<? extends Object>[]`, but not `instanceof List<? extends Object>`

Comment: guys, is it fair to say that `boolean b2` above example now compiles (tested with JDK18) and all became logical now?

Answer (score 1):

Both are the same because all objects in Java extend `Object`. I would prefer `List<?>` because it's more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to how `MyClass extends Object` for every class `List<? extends Object>` is the same as `List<?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm plagiarising Marko, for which I apologise, his comment is the correct answer.

There is no difference, because implicitly every type `extends Object`.