# difference between <?> and <? extends object>

Tags: java, generics

I have this code that is giving me a suppress warning

```
public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
    }
```

The error mentions something about accepting an unchecked conversion so I tried adding `Class<?>` but it also recommended to put in `Class<? extends Object>`. I have read about this before but I can't remember where. I think `<?>` means it accepts any object, and `? extends Object` must mean that the class is a subclass of Object, but isn't that the same thing? Both examples give me no error.

Comment: This question has already been answered [here][1], take a look at it :)

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346622/list-vs-list-extends-object

Comment: ah I should have known, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both are synonymous. So there is no difference

Also check this out:- [Converting Legacy Code to Use Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/convert.html)

Also as notnoop answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016017/unbounded-wildcards-in-java) question there is a very minor difference between the two:

> 1. The JVMS (Java Virtual Machine Specification) has a special specification for the unbounded wildcards, as ClassFileFormat-Java5
>      specifies that unbounded wildcard gets encoded as *, while encodes a
>      Object-bounded wildcard as +Ljava/lang/Object;. Such change would leak
>      through any library that analyzes the bytecode. Compiler writers would
>      need to deal with this issue too. From revisions to "The class File
>      Format"
> 2. From reifiablity standpoint, those are different. JLS 4.6 and 4.7 codify `List<?>` as a reifiable type, but `List<? extends Object>` as a
>      erasured type. Any library writer adding `.isReifiable()` (e.g. mjc lib)
>      needs to account for that, to adhere to the JLS terminology. From JLS
>      4.6 and 4.7.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, they are synonymous. [I found a good answer for the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055389/whats-the-difference-between-and-extends-object-in-java-generics):

By @ruakh:

"

`<?>` and `<? extends Object>` are synonymous, as you'd expect, but there are a few cases with generics where `extends Object` is not actually redundant. For example, `<T extends Object & Foo>` will cause `T` to become `Object` under erasure, whereas with `<T extends Foo>` it will become `Foo` under erasure. (This can matter if you're trying to retain compatibility with a pre-generics API that used `Object`.)

"